# Disabling Macbook Auto-Dimming

Tags: nvidia, xorg, macbook

I was toying around with different kernels on my Macbook Pro, and during the process my Xorg.conf got wiped out. After I rebooted with a more recent kernel, and re-installed the Nvidia driver, I found my screen brightness will change, seemingly randomly.

It normally seems to happen after I resume from suspend, or when I open the System->Administration->NVIDIAa X Server Settings app while plugged in. The brightness will start super bright if I'm in a dim room, or super dim if I'm in a bright room. This normally wouldn't be a problem, but the brightness is usually too extreme, making the screen painful to look at in either scenerio.

Even more frustrating, if I manually set a brightness, it'll reset it a few minutes later. I unchecked the "auto-dimming" option in System->Preferences->Power Management, but it still occurs.

How do I disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a general gnome setting. Assuming you got a recent version of ubuntu,
just install **dconf-editor** and navigate to
**org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power**. The **idle-dim-time** is what you want to change. The value is given in seconds.